# OpenCV more accurate on OS X than Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos, opencv, ubuntu

We've got an OpenCV project that uses its Python bindings to run some motion detection stuff on video files. We've built a series of accuracy tests, using some manually entered input from a tool we built, and we noticed something a little strange.

We're using OpenCV 2.4.9 on OS X, installed via Homebrew, and 2.4.10 on Ubuntu, compiled from source. We've run the tests on a few different machines, and have noticed that our accuracy scores on OS X are much, much higher - averaging around 70%, with the Ubuntu scores averaging around 15%.

What would be the most likely cause of this discrepancy? I would assume that inferior hardware would cause the tests to run more slowly, but am unsure as to what would cause such a drastic change in accuracy. The video codecs, perhaps? Are there any packages for Ubuntu, open-source or otherwise, that are known to improve this?

Dependencies installed:

> sudo apt-get -qq install libopencv-dev build-essential checkinstall
>   cmake pkg-config yasm libjpeg-dev libjasper-dev libavcodec-dev
>   libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libdc1394-22-dev libxine-dev
>   libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libv4l-dev
>   python-dev python-numpy libtbb-dev libqt4-dev libgtk2.0-dev
>   libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev
>   libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev x264 v4l-utils ffmpeg

cmake parameters:

> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
>   -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D
>   BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..

Output of `brew info opencv` on the Macs:

```
opencv: stable 2.4.9, HEAD
http://opencv.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9 (219 files, 38M) *
  Built from source with: --with-gstreamer
From: https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/opencv.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘, pkg-config ✔
Required: jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, libtiff ✔
Recommended: eigen ✘, openexr ✔
Optional: gstreamer ✘, jasper ✘, libdc1394 ✘, openni ✘, qt ✘, tbb ✘, ffmpeg ✔
==> Options
--32-bit
        Build 32-bit only
--c++11
        Build using C++11 mode
--with-cuda
        Build with CUDA support
--with-ffmpeg
        Build with ffmpeg support
--with-gstreamer
        Build with gstreamer support
--with-jasper
        Build with jasper support
--with-java
        Build with Java support
--with-libdc1394
        Build with libdc1394 support
--with-openni
        Build with openni support
--with-qt
        Build the Qt4 backend to HighGUI
--with-quicktime
        Use QuickTime for Video I/O insted of QTKit
--with-tbb
        Enable parallel code in OpenCV using Intel TBB
--with-tests
        Build with accuracy & performance tests
--without-eigen
        Build without eigen support
--without-opencl
        Disable GPU code in OpenCV using OpenCL
--without-openexr
        Build without openexr support
--HEAD
        install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
  mkdir -p
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> homebrew.pth
```

Comment: opencv is quite a wide topic. but I am not certain if (i hope) for the same video you run detection with the same cascade file or you also build the cascade file independently on each machine as well? First step would be to use the same cascade file on both computers.

Answer (score 1):

Variations may come from a codec-related issue as you say, or from the fact that you don't seem to be using the same version of opencv. But the point is, the major difference you observe may very well come from the sensitivity of your test (eg. if something is slightly below some threshold it stops showing up, breaking the whole detection and thus the score) rather than a major difference between installations.

I'd see no other way but to unit-test all `cv2` methods you use to see those who differ between each install. Or at least print some intermediate result during your test procedure, to have more details on where the differences start to appear.

Then you should be able either to understand more about what's going on, or to edit your question with more specific context. Again, I think the global discrepancy value is irrelevant at this stage.